# Pattern for an input Validation that checks 2 letters after dot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have an input that I wrote a pattern for getting domainnames . it works well but I want to check 2 letters after Dot. if my domainname had less that 2 letters after dot i want to show an error.

here is my code:

```
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="Domainname" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+">
    <button type="submit"> check</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{2,}` instead of the last `+`